# Why does the graph of $x^n$ only have an imaginary component if $n$ is not an integer?

Tags: graphing-functions, exponential-function

I was playing around graphing equations and noticed that only non-integer exponents of x yield imaginary graphs. Try it on Wolfram Alpha. Why is that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Joe, do you realise that the green tick denotes your accepted, i.e. favourite, answer? You nominated Jared, then changed it to me then changed it to Nick.

Comment: @FlybyNight You are correct. First there was one answer. Then there were two. Then there were 3. If there is a fourth it may become the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An imaginary component is a component containing $i=\sqrt{-1}=(-1^{\frac{1}{2}})$. Since $(x^{b})^{c}=x^{bc}$, any exponent in the form $x^{\frac{p}{2q}}$, where x is real and $\frac{p}{2q}$ is a reduced fraction so $p$ is not even, can be rewritten as $(x^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{p}{q}}=((\sqrt x)^{p})^{\frac{1}{q}}$. When $x$ is negative this can be seen to be $(i\sqrt{|x|})^{\frac{p}{q}}=(i)^{\frac{p}{q}}(|x|)^{\frac{p}{2q}}$. Since $|x|$ is positive and real $(|x|)^{\frac{p}{2q}}$ is real and since $\frac{p}{q}$ is non-even $(i)^{\frac{p}{q}}$ has an imaginary component. So the graph of $x^{\frac{p}{2q}}$ will have an imaginary component when $x$ is negative.

As [Fly by Night](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/38495/fly-by-night) pointed out in a comment other fractional powers can indeed have imaginary parts because there are $n$ roots of unity for $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Many graphing programs will ignore these if you have an odd root, but a quick check shows that wolfram alpha is not among them and will include the information about the other roots of unity.

An integer power will always have any fractional powers exactly canceled out so that any roots of unity are taken back to unity, that is $1$, by exponentiation. Thus a graph of an integer power of real $x$ should not have an imaginary component.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt[3]x$ has no imaginary component, because negative numbers have real cube roots.  In the example you've given, we can rewrite it as:

$$x^{4.1}=x^4\sqrt[10]x$$

Notice that the even root will have an imaginary part when $x$ is negative.

Comment: Ah, but what of $x^{\sqrt 2}$? :)

Comment: Is the imaginary part $\sqrt[10]x$ less than the real part (in negative x of course)?

Comment: The graph $y = x^{1/3}$ *should* have imaginary components. There are three roots of unity. I suspect you mean $\sqrt[3]{x}$, which is accepted to mean the real value of $x^{1/3}$. A little like $\sqrt{2}$ is accepted to denote the real, positive value of $2^{1/2}$.

Comment: I don't understand why the imaginary component is different in magnitude (y direction) than the real component.

Answer (score 1):

This is natural. For an integer value, say $n$, there is a *unique value* for $x^n$. Simply multiply $x$ with itself $n$ times. Even if $n$ is negative: just divide one by the product of $x$.

\begin{array}{ccc}
x^3 = x \times x \times x \\ \\
x^{-2} = \frac{1}{x \times x}
\end{array}

When you come to non-integer powers, you have to ask yourself what these expressions mean. For example, $x^{1/2}$ stands for a number whose square is $x$. Hence $4^{1/2} = \pm 2$ since $(\pm 2)^2 = 4$. Even for such a simple power as $1/2$, we have two possible $y$ values for each $x$ value when we plot $y=x^{1/2}$.

Note that the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ is different to $x^{1/2}$. The symbol $x^{1/2}$ stands for a number whose square is $x$. The symbol $\sqrt{x}$ stands for the *positive* value of $x^{1/2}$. Hence $2^{1/2} = \pm \sqrt{2}.$

Things get even more tricky when we consider expressions like $x^{1/4}$. What does $x^{1/4}$ mean? It's a number whose fourth power is $x$. For example $1^{1/4} = \pm 1, \pm i$ where $i$ is a complex number and has the property that $i^2=-1$. Trying to plot the graph $y=x^{1/4}$ causes a problem. For all non-zero values of $x$, there are four (possibly complex) values for $y$. That is where the branches come from.

In this case, the symbol $\sqrt[4]{x}$ stands for the positive (real) value of $x^{1/4}$. Hence $2^{1/4} = \pm\sqrt[4]{2}, \pm i \sqrt[4]{2}.$

Comment: Is there any free graphing software (widows, linux, or online) that can graph all 4 values for y? Wolfram Alpha fails to do so: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^%281%2F4%29

Comment: @JoeHobbit It depends what you want. If you only wanted to allow only real values of $x$, then the $y$ values of $y=x^{1/4}$ would still be complex numbers of the form $u+iv$, so you'd end up with something plotted in three dimensional $xuv$-space. I am not aware of any software that can do this easily. If you wanted an accurate picture then you would need to allow complex $x$ and you would get complex $y$, so you would need a four dimensional plot. This would just be impossible.